# How to update 10000 records with 20 randomly chosen values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to update 10000 records with 20 randomly chosen values?

Example: In one table I have fields like firstname, lastname, emailid and it has 10000 records. I want to update an emailid field with test email id list I have.

Comment: no, update all the 10000 rows with 20 values randomly

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Tomek for pointing out the errors and redundancies in the original answer

```
UPDATE PersonalInformation
SET    EmailID = ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6)) % 20)
```

Comment: Have you tested it? It's wrong, the select subquery is optimized and executed just once, so the EmialID will be populated with the same value.

Comment: @Tomek - I have added a testscript that, on my pc, updates to a randomly chosen value from the test list.

Comment: So we both learnt something new, if you try to replace table variables with regular tables it behaves differently.

Comment: @Tomek - You are right, that was unexpected. I have changed the answer.

Comment: +1 on your new answer, you can shorten it to: `UPDATE PersonalInformation SET EmailID = ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6)) % 20)`

Comment: Hi @Lieven quick question for you. Your code works but I did not understand how the inner query is being executed once for each row. Shouldn't it be executed once and the result be applied to all the rows on PersonalInformation? Is it something special with the ABS function? Because if I use "select top 1 ROUND(((18) * RAND() + 1), 0)" it will return the same value always

Comment: @Tomek - I have changed it to the shortened version. Should OP need any ID's <> 1..20, the longer (to adjust) version would have to be used.

Comment: @Diego, the `NEWID` function is executed once for each row in it's current form while when used in an `ORDER BY` (as in the original answer), it was optimized out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
declare @EmailList table
(
    EmailIndex int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    EmailAddress nvarchar(100)
)

insert @EmailList (EmailAddress)
    select 'email1@mailserver.com' union all
    select 'email2@mailserver.com' union all
    select 'email3@mailserver.com'
    -- other emails here...

declare @emailListLength int
select @emailListLength = count (*) from @EmailList

update Users set Email = el.EmailAddress
    from
       (select CEILING(RAND(CONVERT(varbinary, newid())) * @emailListLength) as randomEmailIndex, * from Users) rnd
          join @EmailList el on el.EmailIndex = rnd.randomEmailIndex
```

The `CEILING(RAND(CONVERT(varbinary, newid()))` expression will generate random numbers from `1` to `[email list length]` and then we join the Users table with the predefined enumerated email list using this random index.

Comment: +1 i like the way you're joining on @EmailList.  I probably would have tried row_number() OVER (ORDER BY checksum(*)) or something like that.